# Como fazer contagem de registros em mais de uma tabela?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho essas 3 tabelas:

[image: client]
[image: clientVehicle]
[image: parking]

Quero montar um SELECT que conte o número de registros de cada uma delas.

```sql
SELECT
   COUNT(client.idClient) AS clientQuantity,
   COUNT(clientVehicle.idClientVehicle) AS clientVehicle, 
   COUNT(parking.idParking) AS parkingQuantity 
FROM 
    client,
    clientVehicle,
    parking
WHERE
    client.idClient AND
    clientVehicle.idClientVehicle AND 
    parking.idParking
```

Porém, o resultado é 4 pra todos, sendo que deveria ser, parkingQuantity 1, clientQuantity2 e clientVehicles 2.
Onde estou errado?

Desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: Remova a clausula `WHERE`

Comment: não tem join ai, você adicionou 4 tabelas no `FROM` e não faz link delas, vai retornar um cartesiado de todas, e tudo vai ter o mesmo valor!

Answer (score 0):

Apenas olhando seu `SELECT` e o que tentou fazer no `WHERE`, que supostamente seria o `JOIN` entre as tabelas, posso sugerir esse `SELECT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(client.idClient) AS clientQuantity, 
       COUNT(clientVehicle.idClientVehicle) AS clientVehicle, 
       COUNT(parking.idParking) AS parkingQuantity 
  FROM client
 INNER JOIN clientVehicle ON client.idClient = clientVehicle.idClient
 INNER JOIN parking ON parking.parkingPass = client.parkingPass
```

Note que, na tabela "parking", supostamente o `JOIN` deveria ser pela coluna "idParking", mas pela foto do seu modelo não identifiquei coluna relativa em nenhuma das tabelas, por isso fiz o `JOIN` por "parkingPass"

Comment: Ricardo, rodei seu SQL e retorno 1 em cada um dos valores, ou seja, não deu ainda.

Comment: Não não, parkingPass não tem nada que faça ligação.

Comment: sem um exemplo dos dados não tem como ajudar muito mais. Crie um exemplo aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/  com as tabelas e alguns dados de exemplo para mostrar o que não funciona

Answer (score -1):

Achei uma solução

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   client
    ) AS qttClient,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   parking
    ) AS qttParking,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   clientVehicle
    ) AS qttClientVehicle
FROM    dual
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Aproveitando o select do amigo já
publicado no post, você pode substituir o * pela posição numérica da coluna que deseja contar, nesses casos onde vc quer as colunas de ID que são as primeiras a resposta fica da seguinte forma:

SELECT  (
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM   client
) AS qttClient,
(
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM   parking
) AS qttParking,
(
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM   clientVehicle
) AS qttClientVehicle
FROM    dual